# Why we need Hadoop distributions?

Tags: apache, hadoop, cloudera

I am new to Hadoop. So, please can anybody explain to me why we need cloudera or Hortonworks? We can download each Apache project and use those libraries to create Big Data project, right? And, also if I already use linux OS, do I have to use cloudera-quickstart vm ware? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets look at this in using a similar analogy.

- Lets assume you are using OS 'D' of version 'v1'. In it you need different set of libraries - A,B and C.
- A depends on B and also C depends on B. Across the versions of A and C, the dependencies are different versions of C.

Now if you need all the three libraries, it becomes your head ache to make sure you use/install libraries of each such that each are compatible and there's no clash.

Plus not everyone is expert in all the three libraries as well as the underlying system. So what happens if there some optimization needed in using these libraries while using them in your own tools? Also what about some issues that you face while using them.

That's where these ***"Stack Distributions"*** come into play. Each of these vendors provide a complete stack which is tested as a whole and are compatible with the different libraries that are packaged and not just only hadoop. This makes lives of lots of people easier. Also based on what plan or subscription you have with the vendor, you can get support/training and other auxiliary things.

Just to add as an extra, please remember, Open Source does not necessarily mean Free.(Please note that this is my personal opinion)

As to your other part of question wrt with linux do you need to use any vm ware image or so, for a beginner or learning purposes, this makes your life rather simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the info.